# como puedo cambiar dinamicamente un widget en python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

quiero cambiar un widget etiqueta dinamicamente dependiendo lo que el usuario elija.
por ejemplo si el usuario presiona un boton que dice densidad la etiqueta debe cambiar su texto poniendo "calculando densidad" y el color a amarillo.

intenté crear una variable llamada etiqueta que contenga la informacion del label y así modificarla dependiendo lo que el usuario elija pero me sucede esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se puede ver los widgets se me colapsan uno sobre otro y quisiera solucionar eso.

Answer (score 0):

espero que te encuentres muy bien, te voy a mostrar un ejemplo claro de como se haría una interfaz dinámica con tkinter, pero para esto debes tener muy claro como funciona la programación orientada a objetos en python.

```
import tkinter as tk


class interfaz_dinamica:


    def __init__(self):

        # Se crea la ventana
        self.ventana = tk.Tk() 


        # Se crean los botones
        self.b1 = tk.Button(self.ventana, text='opcion 1', command=self.text1).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=tk.W, pady=4)
        self.b2 = tk.Button(self.ventana, text='opcion 2', command=self.text2).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=tk.W, pady=4)


        # Se crea la etiqueta pero no se le asigna ningun valor
        self.etiqueta = tk.Label(self.ventana)
        # Valor de la etiqueta 
        self.valor = "valor por defecto"

        # se invoca la función dinamica la cual será como un bucle que se ejecuta una y otra vez
        self.funcion_dinamica()
        self.ventana.mainloop()


    # funciones de los botones la cual cambia el contenido de valor
    def text1 (self):
        self.valor = "opcion1"

    def text2 (self):
        self.valor = "opcion2"
        


    def funcion_dinamica(self):


        #se configura la etiqueta con el texto que hay en valor
        self.etiqueta.configure(text = self.valor)
        self.etiqueta.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W,pady=4)

        # se repite nuevamente la funcion dinamica, como si fuera un bucle infinito
        self.etiqueta.after(1,self.funcion_dinamica)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    GUI = interfaz_dinamica()
```

esto es un ejemplo básico lo puedes ejecutar tal cual y ver que pasa con la etiqueta cuando presionas los diferentes botones, sacar tus conclusiones y acoplarlo a tu código, intente que el código este bien comentado y explicado si necesitas ayuda con todo el gusto aquí estaré.